# Twitter update/status API is working on postman and not working in code Android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, postman, twitter-oauth

I am integrating Twitter statuses/update.json API in Android Application.
I am using retrofit for the API.
This API is required `OAuth 1.0` and I am generating all the required values and calling API it is giving me this response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}
```

When I pass all the required values in the Postman it is working.

Here is the way how I am passing values to Postman (form-urlencoded):

[image]

Following is the string which I generated in the code and passing in the header in `Authorization`

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="55pQiiN7hMwSEKMDqc0wYcH",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1617275741",oauth_nonce="675889204f9748a98a7f24c8c313d9bf",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="vuH%2BpCkPNNEr9CnNzT6wXCj2k%3D",oauth_token="2997731-kzHvqPH2NeYnHOV6tFB1wtvXlk1qzUFk3pqUHA",oauth_token_secret="lDOo0Ozyjq2ngdGEr52IOPGxxbsXbWACxZEXLrvlcsO5p",oauth_consumer_secret="tqMmRHJ4kGbykxbOaYD1ZHJgfsKfFSCySpUOGpnIWWH6KjJ"
```

And it is giving me an error as mentioned above.

How I am generating signature:

```
private static String computeSignature(String baseString, String keyString) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(secretKey);

        byte[] text = baseString.getBytes();

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(text))).trim();
    }
```

Am I missing anything? How can I resolve this error?